# Maths Algorithm need help

Tags: algorithms

Hi I'm stuck on this maths question don't really know how to about it. I've tried simultaneous equation to solve for k and c with no success. Hope you can help. I got part 1 but can't get part 2.

---

A program looks up a specific entry in a sorted list of size $n$.  Suppose that the program is implemented on Computer $A$, using a linear search algorithm, and on Computer B, using a binary search algorithm.  Tests are run to compare the algorithms (the run time is measured in nanoseconds):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}n~\text{list size}&A~\text{run time}&B~\text{run time}\\
\hline
10&70~ns&150,000~ns\\
\hline
100&340~ns&200,000~ns\\
\hline
1,000&3,040~ns&250,000~ns\\
\hline
1,000,000&3,000,040~ns&400,000~ns\\
\hline
100,000,000&300,000,040~ns&500,000~ns\end{array}$$

(i) The program run on computer $A$ has a linear growth rate of the form: $f(n)=an+b$.  Find $a$ and $b$.

(ii) The program run on computer $B$ has a logarithmic growth rate of the form: $g(n)=c\ln(n)+k$.  Find $c$ and $k$.

(iii) Use L'Hopital's rule to find the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}$$

and hence determine which algorithm is more efficient for large values of $n$.

Comment: For part (ii), you know that $200000 = c \ln 100 + k = 2c \ln 10 +k$. Combine that with $150000 = c \ln 10 + k$ and it should be pretty easy to solve for $c$ and $k$.

Comment: @Tom You've said you've had no success at finding $a$ and $b$ but you've "got part 1". What did you get for $a$ and $b$? And what have you tried?

Comment: @rogerl I did that and I got 25000 for c and 92436 for k which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @EulCan I got 3 for a and 40 for b

Comment: @Tom You're right about $a$ and $b$ but I think you might have an algebra error for your $c$ and $k$ because those aren't the right values.

Comment: @EulCan Ok I had hose two answers just thought they were wrong because they were large figures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (ii),
$$ 150000 = c \ln 10 + k,\quad 200000 = c\ln 100 + k = 2c\ln 10 + k,$$
so that, subtracting the two equations,
$$ 50000 = c\ln 10\quad\Rightarrow\quad c = \frac{50000}{\ln 10},$$
and then
$$ k = 150000 - c\ln 10 = 150000 - 50000 = 100000.$$

Comment: what do you do for part 3? is this the right idea? 21714ln(n) + 100,000/ 3n + 40